# Select column by startswith during iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe with 100+ columns like that :

[image]

For example, I want to assign the incident type column `'Malware'` during `iterrows()` if the column name starts with `'action.malware'` and if the column value is `True`.

I wanted to do something like:

```
for index, value in df3.iterrows():
    if value.startswith('action.malware'): #line2
        df3.loc[i,value]== True:           #line3
            df3.loc[i,'Incident Type'] = 'Malware'
```

and got `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'` on line2
and

```
File "<ipython-input-151-895039092064>", line 3
    df3.loc[i,value]== True:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

on line3.

Im unsure how to `loc` the columns in the proper way in line 2 and 3 because my `value` in `iterrows()` returns a set of column+column value instead of a single column name. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: [You should never modify something you are iterating over](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows).

Comment: You are expected to add a sample data as text, as we can not copy the content from the  image. You can print `df.head().to_dict()`, and add the output to the question. Taking about the your problem, You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter out the required columns based on the name or  pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` as suggested by @ThePyGuy to select columns and `any` to check if at least one value is `True` in the selected columns:

Sample:

```
>>> df
   action.phishing.A  action.malware.B  action.malware.C  action.malware.D
0              False             False             False              True
1               True             False             False             False
2              False              True             False             False
```

```
>>> df.loc[df.filter(like='action.malware').any(axis=1), 'Incident Type'] = 'Malware'

   action.phishing.A  action.malware.B  action.malware.C  action.malware.D Incident Type
0              False             False             False              True       Malware
1               True             False             False             False           NaN
2              False              True             False             False       Malware
```